# Is it possible to import user profile from an external source, not from active directory

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, authentication, sql

How do I import user profile directly from an external source (`SQL database`) without using active directory?

The common usual solution is to have a SharePoint privilege account that have the `replicate directory changes` to start the user profile synchronization service and then use the Business Connectivity Service of SharePoint to connect to a `SQL`.

However in my project, we are unable to get the `replicate directory changes` privilege to the account.

Thus, is it possible to start the User Profile Synchronization Service WITHOUT granting the 
1) Replicate Directory Changes in the AD 
2) Granting the domain user account "sp_farm" the local admin account
so that we can synchronize the user profile using BCS from an external data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synchronize using [BDC](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/18/how-to-create-userprofile-synchronization-connection-to-bcs-and-map-user-profile-property-to-bcs-field-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Comment: i found this article. however, it still requires me to start the user profile synchronization service before i can create a new connection. And that will require  SharePoint privilege account (spfarm, spprofileservice etc) that have the replicate directory changes. to my understanding, that requires an AD right?

Comment: I don't think. Replication Rights are AD permissions, right, but in this case you'll configure your synchronization on Business Data Catalog, that means an SQL DB. I don't see any references to AD.

Comment: in my SharePoint 2013, when i go to Configure Profile Synchronization -> Add New Connection -> it shows me an error message "Cannot navigate to the request page because User Profile Synchronization Service is not running. Please start the User Profile Synchronization Services before creating a connection" and when i try to start the User Profile Synchronization Services it fails. one of the possible explanation for the failure is that the account doesnt have replicate directory changes

Comment: Do you know why does it fail? best way is to track the ULS logs on the server you're starting it.

Comment: Failure retrieving application ID for User Profile Application Proxy 'User Profile Service App': Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have 3fb1994c-eedf-4394-a1c2-e74b0790dc0b     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_AppID()

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24839.sharepoint-2013-userprofileapplicationnotavailableexception-profilepropertycache-does-not-have.aspx